# using a local variable globally in your class PHP

Tags: php, laravel

I know this is a noob question in php but what is the best way to access a local variable globally? For example

```
class myClass {

    $mainuser = new MainUser();

     $mainuser->run(function() {
            $tenantuser = TenantUser::create([
                'first_name' => request('first_name'),
                'last_name' => request('last_name'),
                'username' => request('first_name'),
                'role' => 'user',
                'email' => request('email'),
                'phone_number' => request('phone_number'),
            ]);
        });
    return $tenantuser;

}
```

How can i use $tenantuser in my class?

Comment: If you trying to access it from within the same class you can use $this->myvariable to access class variables, you would first need to set the variable!

Comment: I think you need to do a little basic research regarding [Classes and Objects](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php) in PHP.  What you have now won't even run, let alone do what you want.

Comment: @PatrickQ i stripped down my code to the most important part. Already got my answer though. Thanks

Comment: @PatrickObafemi  What you did was make a completely unusable bit of code that make it impossible to provide you with an answer.  Please keep that in mind when asking future questions.  Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) on providing a minimal _reproducible_ example.

Comment: @PatrickQ alright. Thank you. WIll keep that in mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
class myClass
{

    public function get_mainuser()
    {
        $mainuser = new MainUser();
        $tenantuser = null;
        $mainuser->run(function () use (&$tenantuser) {
            $tenantuser = TenantUser::create([
                'first_name'   => request('first_name'),
                'last_name'    => request('last_name'),
                'username'     => request('first_name'),
                'role'         => 'user',
                'email'        => request('email'),
                'phone_number' => request('phone_number'),
            ]);
        });
        return $tenantuser;
    }


}

$myClass = new myClass();
print_r($myClass->get_mainuser());
```

Comment: Thanks @Dmitry that did it for me

Answer (score -2):

you can declare a variable for a class first then assign a value for that variable, now you can access that `tenantuser` variable outside the function also i.e., globally

```
class myClass {
public $tenantuser;
$mainuser = new MainUser();

 $mainuser->run(function() {
            $this->tenantuser = TenantUser::create([
            'first_name' => request('first_name'),
            'last_name' => request('last_name'),
            'username' => request('first_name'),
            'role' => 'user',
            'email' => request('email'),
            'phone_number' => request('phone_number'),
        ]);
    });
return $this->tenantuser;
}
```

Comment: thanks but i tried that first but $this->tenantuser returned null